# How should a radio receiver be used to detect damage to concealed wiring?

Tags: wiring, receiver, damage

Several structures hereabouts date back to the mid 1920s. Electrical wires were insulated by cloth winding, and embedded in Wooden Trunking

[image: Wooden trunking]

With the passage of time the cloth rotted away in some places (typically near a junction/bend) leaving raw wires in the wooden channels. Come rain, and there may be the occasional experience of an electrical kit kat fuse growing warm, even hot!

The electrician says, in his experience, even opening the channel cover for inspection strips all the cloth insulation off the wires for a few feet both up-and-down the work area.

What I'd like to do is determine any points where the cloth insulation has already rotted into dust.

With 220V 50Hz in the line, I figure there may be some radiation around the wiring which could be detected by the right receiver. Similarly where the insulation is exposed, perhaps, the radiated signal may be stronger. Obviously it won't be an intelligible signal - even strong/stronger/weaker static may serve.

My questions

- Is this idea feasible?
- What is the strength of such radiation?
- What frequency band should such receiver aim to detect?

Comment: Most unlikely, any field around the wire would not produce a measurable effect due to the presence or absence of a thin insulation layer. Add to that the wire in 'buried' in a wooden box so even if there was an effect it would be totally masked.

Comment: If the bad wires get warm, then an ir camera might show them up

Comment: If you are talking about "Knob & Tube" wiring, it's the best wiring design ever invented. Good for wet environments. Its drawback is expanding the system, you can't. The feed through of wood should be in porcelain tubes. Wire runs are supported by porcelain standoff insulators. Use fuses that limit the current to safe levels, don't cheat. Friction tape splices.

Comment: If my house or office had this kind of wiring, I would not hesitate to rip it all out and replace it.  It's a time bomb.  There is little sense in building a detector, in my opinion.

Comment: @DavidKessner: Cost is a factor with the residents. The ultimate aim is to replace all of it beginning with the 'hot' spots; hence the detector.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: Good idea! I'll keep it in reserve though ; locating an IR cam may take a bit of effort

Comment: @Everyone  I'm just saying that, were it me living there, I would not accept anything less that "replace it all right now".  And the cost and time required to develop a detector would negate the "right now" part of that.  Anything less would be a higher risk that when _I_ would be comfortable with.

Comment: @Everyone  Just go to amazon.com and search for Thermal Camera.

Comment: @Optionparty: Not "Knob & Tube" wiring; these are loom wires running through dedicated wood channels. Porcelain/Bakelite cut-outs serve as junction/fuse boxes. I'll try to get a photograph.

Comment: @Optionparty Added the photograph. Have learnt since the term for this kind of wiring is 'Trunking'. Fantastically safe (ceramic stand-off, then trunking with distinct channels for live, and neutral wires) except for where it's been got at by the modern workman who, amongst other things, took the opportunity to squeeze multiple wires into a channel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cotton braiding will not be doing anything useful RF-wise (attenuation or modification) that means you could determine its presence or not or general condition. A broken or short-circuited copper core may give off some detectable signal, but that's not your question.

A simple oscilloscope-based [Time Domain reflectometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-domain_reflectometer) could help tracing faulty cables, but they only really show breaks, shorts, changes of impedance, etc. and on short runs (<100m) you need relatively fast/expensive measurement.

In your situation, an undesirable bare copper wire touching bare dry wood will likely not be detected. If the wood was damp (hence conductive), or the wire was touching a nail or similar, then it's *possible* you might pick it up, but you'd need a pretty sensitive setup.

Basic TDR's are DIY-able with a simple pulse-generator circuit and any oscilloscope, but results may vary greatly. They're used commercially in telecomms on both copper & fibre-optics to qualify & fault-locate cables and the good ones are really great bits of kit. Due to the speed of light/electrons, short cables present quite a challenge.

Comment: Electrons aren't fast. Waves travelling in them are. http://amasci.com/miscon/speed.html

Comment: @PhilFrost: I thought that until one got to really incredibly low temperatures electrons were very fast, but spend most of their time whizzing around atoms rather than between them.

Comment: @supercat yes, that's true, but the usage here seemed to suggest that their motion due to current was fast. The physics of electrons can be another discussion; I just did not want to allow a common misconception to propagate.

Comment: Phil, I think you're taking it a bit more seriously than it was written. Also, it doesn't actually make any difference to the answer, the point being "short cables need fast measurements".